# Pydrive authentication using

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I was using gdata module to access, upload, download files from google doc. I have the oauth key and secret with me. Now I want to switch to google drive api. Learning and studying a bit on google drive api , it looks like a bit different in the authentication. I also have downloaded pydrive module so as I can start things up. But I am not able to authorize my server side python code to authorize/authenticate the user using my oauth keys and access my drive. Do any one has any spare know how on how I can use pydrive to access my drive with my previous auth keys. I just need a simple way to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

For using the gdata module we use either of these credentials-
1> username & password or
2> consumer oauth key and secret key.

Since you are trying to use oauth credentials, I think you want a Domain Wide Delegated Access for Google Drive, which will help you to achieve uploading/downloading files into any user's google drive through out the domain.

For this you need to generate a new Client ID of a Service Account Type from
[Developer's Console](http://console.developers.google.com)

*.p12 file will get downloaded. Note the path where you save it. 
  Also note the email address of your Service account. These will be use while coding.

Below is the python code where u have to carefully edit-
PATH TO SERIVE ACCOUNT PRIVATE KEY, something@developer.gserviceaccount.com, EMAIL_ID@YOURDOMAIN.COM  in order to run it properly and test it.

Hope this will help!
Resource- [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

"""Email of the Service Account"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'something@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

"""Path to the Service Account's Private Key file"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'PATH TO SERIVE ACCOUNT PRIVATE KEY'

def createDriveService(user_email):
  """Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
  that act on behalf of the given user.

  Args:
    user_email: The email of the user.
  Returns:
    Drive service object.
  """
  f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', sub=user_email)
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

drive_service=createDriveService('EMAIL_ID@YOURDOMAIN.COM')

result = []
page_token = None


while True:
    try:
        param = {}
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
        files = drive_service.files().list().execute()
        #print files
        result.extend(files['items'])
        page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
        break

for f in result:
    print '\n\nFile: ',f.get('title')

    print "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks Jai for your pretty . Let me try with this stuff and check it out... thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I have mentioned the source in my answer- Google Drive API, kindly visit the link to get the code in other different languages java, php, javascript etc. Also don't forget to Vote My Answer ;)

Comment: I Know this is a late reply :). I tried the code and also created a service account and then made the required changes in the domain admin under security as in [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account), under Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account. But when I try from other user under the domain using the sub=myuser@mydoamin.com, its giving me 'invalid_grant'. Dont know how to figure where things gets issue. Checking pdb_trace(), the credential object does not have the credential.access_token, rob in build.

Comment: From Developers Console did u generate CLIENT ID of Service Account Type, with the Domain Admin account?

Comment: After some more homework ,I found that the email(service acc) so created was not valid. Might be that I created the service account from a normal user under the domain. I removed the previous service account, and I used a service account created using the domain user account and it works. cheers...